# Magento database query to get number of products for a price range

Tags: magento

I have statically added price range with hyperlinks:

- $0 - $500
- $500 - $1,000
- $1,000 - $2,500
- $2,500 - $5,000
- $5,000 - $10,000
- $10,000 - $15,000
- $15,000 and up

For example, when I click the link $1000-$2500, the url is 
`http://localhost/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?price[from]=1000&price[to]=2500&category=9`. This is working fine. I want to display the number of products for each price range only by checking the price field in the table. What might be the query?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that you can use Layered Navigation for this purposes? This is kind of navigation which will show filters on product collection in the left column of you category's products list page  (in default theme). Default kind of filter is price. To enable layered navigation you should go to properties of category and there in `Display Settings` set `Is Anchor` to `true`. You could manually specify step for filters. The first way to do this is in admin backend menu `System -> Configuration`, and there `Catalog->Catalog->Layered Navigation`. The second way is to change it in the properties of category: `Display Settings -> Layered Navigation Price Step`